# Angular 4 select option *ngIf

Tags: angular4

Здравствуйте. У меня есть поле статус. Хочу сделать так, если значение 1 то второй option будет 0. Когда открываю modal все правильно показывает, а когда изменяю значение не правильно работает. Вот кода и картинка до и после. Буду очень благодарен.

```
<select #status="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="category.status" class="form-control">
   <option>{{category.status}}</option>
   <option *ngIf="category.status === 1">0</option>
   <option *ngIf="category.status === 0">1</option>
</select>
```

[image: До]

[image: После]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
<select #status="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="category.status" class="form-control">
   <option [selected]="category.status === 1">0</option>
   <option [selected]="category.status === 0">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: работает. спасибо. но можно сделать так чтобы в открывающем option не было то значения который уже стоит?
Пример
http://prntscr.com/helzpv